# Dynamic Formatting of a fixed point number

Tags: c++, floating-point, string-formatting

I need to format a floating point number (represented as a `std::string`) where the output will have 14 digits at max, including both the integral part and the decimal part.

While being limited to 14 digits, the integral part can have upto 14 digits (then there is no decimal part) and the decimal part can have maximum of 7 digits (then 7 digits for the integral part)

```
**Examples**
123
123.456
12345678901234
1234567.89
1234.5678901
1234567890123.4
1234567890123.456 // Invalid; Should be transformed to 1234567890123.4
123456789012345.6 // Invalid; Should be transformed to 12345678901234
```

The idea is to retain the `length =< 14`, where the maximum number of decimal numbers is 7. **In the end, I also need to add the thousand separators as well**.

**Current approach**
Currently, I try to split the string using the decimal point and extract the two parts of the number. (If there is no `"."`, it will be handled by separately). Then the sizes are checked for integral part and decimal part.

However, since this is not straight forward, this fails in some cases.

**But my question is:**

Is there any easy way, that I can use without all these mess?

Comment: What do you do when you have more than 14 digits?  What do you do when you have more than 7 decimal places?  Are you rounding or just truncating?

Comment: Maybe you could use `std::set_precision` along with `std::ostringstream`?

Comment: @NathanOliver : Truncation would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward and seems to work according to your specification.

```
std::string format(string str)
{
    // Are there any decimals?
    int dot = str.find(".");
    if (dot < 0)
    {
        return str.substr(0, 14);
    }

    std::string integral = str.substr(0, dot);
    size_t intlength = integral.length();

    // Too long to care about decimals?
    if (intlength >= 14)
    {
        return integral.substr(0, 14);
    }

    // Keep at most seven decimals
    std::string decimals = str.substr(dot + 1, 7);
    size_t declength = decimals.length();

    // Is concatenation short enough?
    if (intlength + declength <= 14)
    {
        return integral + "." + decimals;
    }

    return integral + "." + decimals.substr(0, 14 - integral.length());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I add the thousand separators?

Comment: Okay, I used `std::stringstream` with `ss.imbue(std::locale(""))` and `std::fixed` on the integral part (after converting to an int). It worked. Thanks a lot.!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Boost.Format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/format/doc/format.html). Here's an example that passes your test cases:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#include <boost/format.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> examples = {
        "123",
        "123.456",
        "12345678901234",
        "1234567.89",
        "1234.5678901",
        "1234567890123.4",
        "1234567890123.456",
        "123456789012345.6" 
    };
    std::string format = "%1$.15s";
    for (auto example : examples)
    {
        std::cout << boost::format(format) % example << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice but this does not limit the decimal part to 7 or less digits.  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b36f6cf14b462852

Comment: I need to do it with C++, without using external libraries. But thanks anyway. :)